# Unable to resize the screen when keyboard pops up

Tags: flutter

I want to resize the screen when the keyboard pops up, but I am unable to achieve it using the given code. What's the issue? Here is my code

```
 Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
       body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: TextField(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: try to add `padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),` padding in your `Container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already had some errors, I refactored it and corrected it, now it works and the screen resizes, it was not working because you didn't add a `SingleChildScrollView` to wrap the stack, because without it some of the content can not fit to the screen when it resizes

```
  return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: TextField(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```